# PHP PDO CRUD class Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo

I'm just getting started using PDO to move away from mysqli but hit a problem. I'm following a tutorial and I want to return an array from the database but I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptuts\crud\core\managedb.class.php on line 27

Here is my managedb.php class:

```
<?php

class ManageDatabase
{

    public $link;

    function __construct()
    {
        include_once('database.class.php');
        $conn = new database;
        $this->link = $conn->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }

    function getData($table_name, $id=null)
    {
        if(isset($id))
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id = '$id' ORDER BY id ASC");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY id ASC");
    }

    $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
    if($rowCount >= 1)
    {
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
    }
    else
    {
        $result = 0;
    }
    return $result;
}

}
```

Then I'm simply using the following code to try and get a response:

```
<?php

include_once('../core/managedb.class.php');
$init = new ManageDatabase;

$table_name = 'users';
$data = $init->getData($table_name);

print_r($data);
```

This is when I get the error, Any ideas?

Comment: You should use a prepared query's if your passing parameters `$id`

Comment: Ok I put the SQL directly into phpmyadmin and got the results I expected, but its returning me a bool(false) when doing a var_dump direct in the script, so I guess something is going wrong in my $rowCount function I just can't work out what.

Answer (score 1):

I'd `var_dump($query)` before the `$rowCount = $query->rowCount();` line to see what it actually is, because apparently it's not an object.  I'm guessing it's either NULL or empty because the whole `$this-link->query(<sql statement>);` didn't return what you expected

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks getting me on the right track, I get this when doing the dump: bool(false)

Comment: If $query is bool(false) that means that the query string is somehow not correct. You should also var_dump the query string and make sure it is correct, and also var_dump $this->link to make sure it's correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check out:

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

You'll want to test if the query succeed and if not, why. You can check the error using PDO's [`errorInfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) function:

```php
if ($query == false) 
{
    print_r($this->link->errorInfo());
    exit();
}
```

Another thing to note is that `rowCount()` in PDO returns the affected rows from a INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE type statement. For a SELECT you may get a row count, or you may not. The manual suggests a separate query to find the number of rows, but in your instance it might be easier testing if you get anything back from fetchAll():

```php
$result = $query->fetchAll();
if (!empty($result)) 
{
    return $result;
} 
else 
{
    return 0;
}
```